# Does disabling a views features module remove the view from the DB

Tags: 7, views, features

Inherited a site with 3 [features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) modules, one is just a collection of *`views`*. i disabled it in the features interface. expecting it to disable all the views that were defined in that features module. but nothing happened... the site is huge (full publishing house)

I disabled it because theme hooks were not being applied think this has something to do with the way features is implemented.

I would like to know if once you've imported a `views` only [features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module it is imported to the db. and i can continue believing that i've broken nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling features will not disable all views in that features.
Feature is only used to export configurations,views etc to avoid manual work. You need to disable view from its UI page.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you disable that Views feature module, all Views including in there will not be disabled, you have to disable them  manually (or use `drush views-disable`). The reason is that , as mentioned (@kannan),in features are tracked settings, configurations and code, like Views code, and there your Views are living, in code, not in the database, that's why you can't see them in your database, so you haven't done something wrong :)

Have you correct implement your [hook_themes](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) (don't forget `drush cc all` after any hook  implementation), because there are no many ways (actually there is only one) to implement a feature in Drupal